# How do I make a if the id is not mine in discord.js

Tags: discord.js

How do I make if the person is not me then I will cancel the command saying sorry you are not (my name)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd create a file in the same directory called "config.json" with the content

`{"my-id": "your-id-here"}` and put `const config = require("./config.json");` at the top of the document. Now you have the variabele `config.my-id` what you can use to create your if statement, like this: `if (message.author.id !== config.my-id) return message.channel.send("Sorry, you aren't me!");`

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```js
if (message.author.id !== 'Your ID') return;
```